# Overall CPU utilization% of 'htop' is smaller than a process' cpu usage

Tags: process, cpu-load, top, htop

Because of my stupidity, I can't provide any screenshot of such phenomenon. My 2-core system's cpu utilization(which is output of htop command) is smaller than the cpu usage of a process.

For example,

- utilization of core0 is 13%
- utilization of core1 is 23%
- CPU usage(%CPU) of a multithreaded(about 30 threads) process is 54%

How can this possible? I'm currently reading code of htop, but I can't find any clue..

Comment: Your 30 threads would likely have scheduling wait times, for an available CPU. That would not show in the CPU utilization, but might be included in your process stuff. It should also reflect in the load average. do `uptime`. For example, I am running 2500 threads right now and each of 12 CPUs show about 13% utilization but the load average is 20.

Comment: Thank you for comment!! But I still have some questions about your comment. What exactly is 'scheduling wait times'? Do you mean the duration of time which a thread is in runqueue, but not executing? A process' cpu usage is calculated by utime+stime/total_time, and each time is calculated by tick, so I don't think waiting in runqueue is accounted in utime and stime... Can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: I can't really elaborate, it was just a thought, backed up by a possibly not relevant example.

Comment: I ran 30 threads on my little test program and ran htop at 30 seconds per sample, did a frame grab, and summed manually: Total CPU usage by summing CPUs: 191.4%; Total program usage by summing each thread: 190.4%